# Is my stat_summary considering all points for calculating the mean?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My code is as follows:

```
ggplot(data=ICL1, aes(x=as.Date(AÑO_MES), y=IndICL1, group=RUN_FM, colour=RUN_FM)) +
 ylim(0,150)+ xlab("Periodo") + ylab("% Cobertura") + 
geom_hline(aes(yintercept=100),colour="red")+
stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="line",size=1.5 , mapping = aes (group = 1),colour="green") + geom_point()
```

The thing is that with this I receive the following message: *"Removed 153 rows containing missing values (stat_summary)"*

This is because these points are beyond my **`ylim(0,150)`**, which I use it like this because the scale gives a properly view of what I want to show.

I want to know if with this message, `stat_summary` is considering this missing points for calculating the mean ?... If not, what should I do to consider this points in the mean calculation but not showing them in the graphs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `coord_cartesian()` to change the range that is *displayed*. As you've discovered, `ylim()` and `xlim()` affect the range of data that is actually used to calculate and generate the plot.

In your case, you should replace the `ylim` with `coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 150))`.

Comment: The help file for `ylim`  states this (and the correct alternative) very clearly.

Comment: Needing to state this so frequently in the documents (plus the weight of people getting it wrong anyway) strongly suggests this particular design decision was wrong. I hope ggplot2's designer finds some way of fixing it in future (though this is of course hard now it's baked in!)